# When I am by myself, I am negative

Tags: riddle, word

> When I am by myself, I'm negative.
> Give me 2, and I'll read the same.
> But if you halve me, I always seem surprised.
> Tack on a cliff, and I become smarter.
> A dreaded word I am...

**What am I?**

The answer is a single word.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are the word:

> **NO**

*When I am by myself, I'm negative.*

> The word **NO** is used to give a *negative* response.

*Give me 2, and I'll read the same.*

> Add 2 letters (specifically, a K at the front and a W at the back) and you have the word **KNOW**, a homophone when read aloud.

*But if you halve me, I always seem surprised.*

> Half of 'NO' is merely **O**, which sounds like 'oh', an expression of *surprise*.

*Tack on a cliff, and I become smarter.*

> Add **LEDGE** (a *cliff*) and you have NOLEDGE or **KNOWLEDGE**, something which makes a person *smarter*.

*A dreaded word I am...*

> People rarely wish to hear a response of 'NO' when they make a request or ask a question. Unless of course the question is "What is an abbreviation for 'number'?" or "Who was that Dr from the James Bond film...?"

Comment: Nice exceptions at the end, haha